# Selenium not hooking to Flash web application in Firefox

Tags: python, selenium, flash

I'm using Selenium in Python to automate a flash game by clicking on the flash application in the web browser. The code is very simple; go to the URL, click the flash game and send w a s d keys with the send_keys() function. This works fine with the chrome driver. My problem is when I do the same in Firefox, the flash window doesn't respond to the keys being sent. Is there a reason Firefox doesn't respond and Chrome does? If so, are there settings I can change to make it work for Firefox?

Here is a simple example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

browser = webdriver.Chrome()

browser.get("https://www.agame.com/game/red-ball")

def play():
    screen = browser.find_element_by_id("flashgame")
    screen.click()
    time.sleep(1)
    for i in range(100):
        time.sleep(0.1)
        screen.send_keys("w")
```

Once the code has ran, you will need to manually enable flash and start the game, so the player is in the first level. At this point, running the play() function will start the player jumping.

If we change the webdriver to Firefox while using the same code, the player does not jump even though the element is selected:

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
```

I'm guessing this is due to how Firefox handles the input?

Note: To activate flash go to:

Chrome: chrome://settings/content/flash (ask first)

Firefox: about:addons -> plugins -> shockwave flash (ask to activate)

Comment: That does seem weird. Can you show the code you are using?

Comment: I've updated the post with an example, hope this helps